# Playing received NSData from an HTTP POST request using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, http-post, nsdata, avaudioplayer, gcdwebserver

Here is the code where the POST handler for the local web server is implemented. It downloads the song in the form of NSData( (request as! GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest).data ) at the server which is uploaded from the client device.

```
 webServer.addHandlerForMethod("POST",path:"/", requestClass: GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest.self, processBlock:
        {request in
 let html: String = String(format: "<html><body><p>hi</p></body></html>")
 NSLog("Request Args %hhd bkmbk", (request as! GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest).hasBody())

 NSLog("Request Args %@ bkmbk", (request as! GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest).contentType)
```

With this method, NSData of song file is successfully received at the server side. The size of the data received corresponds to the actual file sent. **When the received song is tried to play it plays only a part of it and then it stops.** However, the application as a whole does not crash.

```
 do{
  print((request as! GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest).data.length)
  let player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: (request as! GCDWebServerURLEncodedFormRequest).data, fileTypeHint: "mp3")
  player.prepareToPlay()
  player.play()
        }catch{
           // ...
        }
        return GCDWebServerDataResponse(HTML:html)
    })
```

All the methods above are performed in AppDelegate.swift and are performed in a background thread.
Any help to resolve the issue is highly appreciated. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that the `AVAudioPlayer` instance is not kept around since it is in a local variable. When `return GCDWebServerDataResponse(HTML:html)` is called, the local variable and the player are destroyed.